# Where does actionscript 3.0 pick up its params from?

Tags: actionscript-3, flashvars

in AS2.0 you would include key->val style params in the param embed and object strings and then when running the SWF you would pick them up via the _root object. So in your HTML you would say foo=bar

and then in your movie you could go and retrieve _root.foo

Obviously they've removed _root altogether in AS3.0 and I'm now at a loss as to what the mechanism is for retrieving those variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah... found it
root.loaderInfo.parameters.foo;

Maybe someone else will find this useful, I'll leave it up.